# Упростить блок с заменой текста str.gsub!

Tags: строки, парсер, ruby

Есть такой кусочек кода

```
      repl = sub.gsub!("#empty#", "\\thispagestyle{empty}")
      repl = sub.gsub!("#remtxt#", "\\remtxt")
      repl = sub.gsub!("#verse#", "\\begin{mdframed}[style=verse]\n\\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}\n\\setstretch{1.05}\n")
      repl = sub.gsub!("#end#", "\\end{mdframed}")
```

Некий конвертор в `tex`

Как можно упростить этот участок? (планируется добавить еще штук пять таких замен)
Имею в виду использовать массив, вместо постоянного вызова функции.

Comment: Не надо тут ничего "упрощать". Все правильно сделано.

Comment: Думаю, целесообразно вынести пары  в массив, чтобы подключать как дополнительный модуль. 
И расширять перечень так будет проще.

Comment: Ничего не мешает это вынести в модуль так, как есть. А для расширения перечня в текстовом редакторе есть кнопка "дублировать текущую строку".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте массив `a[i][2]` пар значений (как пример `{"#empty#", "\\thispagestyle{empty}"}`).

Потом в цикле перебирайте его и запускайте `repl = sub.gsub!(a[i][0], a[i][1])`.

Примерный код:

```rb
a.each do |x| repl = sub.gsub!(x[0], x[1]) end
```

Только массив нужно предварительно заполнить. Если это сделать константами в коде, то особого выигрыша и не будет. А можно данные считывать из файла, и это уже будет некоторый выигрыш, так как в файле можно менять данные без изменения самого кода.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, у вас есть контент следующего содержания:

```rb
content = "#empty#\n#end#"
```

И hash с такими подстановками:

```rb
subs = {
  empty: "\\thispagestyle{empty}",
  remtxt: "\\remtxt",
  end: "\\end{mdframed}",
}
```

Применить все подстановки к `content` можно с помощью метода [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```rb
result = subs.keys.inject(content) do |sum, k|
  sum.gsub("##{k}#", subs[k])
end
```

Результат вывода `puts result`:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: Хочу отметить, что в этом решении hash перебирается аж два раза(!) (или три?): сначала строится массив ключей, потом по нему идёт итерация, а потом по ключу ищется значение. А можно было работать хотя бы с парами ключ/значение?

Comment: gsub или gsub! Первая вроде не меняет исходную строку

Comment: @Igor, блок кода, который передается в метод `inject`, возвращает значение, поэтому используется именно `gsub`.

Comment: @rotabor, экономия на спичках, если элементов немного, то разница несущественная. Алгоритмическая сложность линейная. Субъективно так код лучше читается.